# Wrap div around results

Tags: nodes, theming

In a content node, I wanted to wrap a div around some results.
For example:
I have this inputs:

Image
Title
Body
Address
Email
Name

And I wanted to have divs like this:
DIV
Image
Title
/DIV
DIV
body
Adress
Email
/DIV
DIV
Name
/DIV

Is this in any way possible?

Comment: Have you thought about  creating a custom node.tpl.php for the content type (https://www.drupal.org/node/17565) then pulling the field values wrapped with anything you want?

Comment: I thought about. But how do I divide the results in different divs on php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you create a new .tpl.php for your content type, you can simply print the divs as html, and echo the vars as php.

example:

```
<div class="MyClass">
<?php print $title; ?>
</div>
<div class="MyOtherClass">
<?php echo render($content['some_field']); ?>
</div>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074485/drupal-7-how-to-render-custom-field for a starting point on pulling specific custom fields, for separation, if needed.

be sure to have a copy of your original node.tpl.php in your theme folder as well, or your node--my-content-type.tpl.php wont work! Again, see https://www.drupal.org/node/17565.

Comment: I could kiss you, Daniel! It worked!